# Recursive file rename behaving incorrectly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to prefix all .ascx files in my project folder with an underscore in the filename. The Powershell I have written is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.ascx' -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {"_$($_.Name)"}
```

This has done as intended for most of the files but for some it has prepended the filenames with a large number of underscores. For example:
MyDirectory/MySubDirectory1/____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________Filename.ascx

I can't understand why this is happening. I initially ran the script with the --whatif parameter and the results using that seemed to be correct.

Keeping my eye on the terminal I get many of these exceptions:

```
Rename-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
At line:1 char:47
+ ... lter '*.ascx' -File -Recurse|Rename-Item -NewName {"_$($_.Name)"}
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\MyUser...pportPanel.ascx:String) [Rename-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Muppet\Desktop\test' -Filter '*.ascx' -File -Recurse 

ForEach ($file in $files)
         { 
           $newname = "_" + $file.Name
           Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $newname
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know **how** you created the multiple underscores, it shouldn't occur with:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.ascx' -File -Recurse|Rename-Item -NewName {"_{0}" -f $_.Name}
```

To repair the underscores use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '__*.ascx' -File -Recurse|Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '(?<=^_)_+'}
```

Comment: Your suggestion above yields the same results as the one I used, I didn't realise before that it was actually throwing loads of exceptions, I have added this detail into the question. I get the same exceptions running your suggestion above. Your repair script works well to correct any that went wrong however. Thank you for that!

Comment: That didn't happen here (with a different ext), but it also didn't happen with your own command, so I'm curious. If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: I will post back here if I find out ever. I have voted it up but my reputation is too low for it to show I believe